# Call function inside iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery

im trying to do something here. I have a document which I set an array. Then, jquery takes this array and appends an iframe for each value:

```
<script>
  var containers = new Array("test1", "test2");
</script>
```

This results is 2 iframes, identified by id with his name. Ok. perfect, working. Then, inside of each iframe, it calls a document. Inside this document, I have a function called `play()`.

I am testing `play()` by returning an alert. Whenever I click on a button, it works:

```
$("#viewport .next").click(function(){
    document.getElementById(containers[current]).contentWindow.play();
});
```

This works. Perfectly. But I it put this function to trigger on document ready, it doesnt works.

```
$(function() {
    document.getElementById(containers[current]).contentWindow.play();
});
```

It returns to me:

`Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Window] has no method 'play'`

Whats am I doing wrong guys?
Thanks!

**EDIT**

Tried to apply onload on iframe. Didnt work.

```
var initialFrame = containers[qual];

initialFrame.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById(initialFrame).contentWindow.play();
};
```

**EDIT2**

For some reason, it started working. Thanks!

Comment: Wait for the `iframe`'s `load` event.

Comment: Its working, thanks! onload was necessary!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wait for the `load` event of the `iframe` first.

```
initialFrame.addEventListener("load", function() {
    initialFrame.contentWindow.play();
});
```

Comment: contentWindow does not work on IE. How to let it work with IE?

Answer (score 0):

You would generally listen for the iframe's load event like this:

```
$("#iframe").load(function(){
    // iframe is loaded
});
```

... but I had trouble with this recently so I instead checked for the contents of the iframe over and over until it had loaded, like this:

```
function loadFrame() {
    if($('body', $('#iframe').contents()).length != 1) {
        setTimeout(loadFrame,500);
    }
    else {
        // iframe is loaded
    }
};
loadFrame();
```

Not sure if this is the best solution, but it works.